# How to get correct size of substring?

Tags: regex, unicode, erlang, diacritics

I would like to match substring correctly.

```
re:run("étude", "é",[unicode]).
```

The result of running this code is `{match,[{0,2}]}`. This result looks like I use unnormilize Unicode string.

So next I try to add normalization:

```
re:run(unicode:characters_to_nfc_list("étude"), unicode:characters_to_nfc_list("é"),[unicode]).
```

The result was the same: `{match,[{0,2}]}`

How to describe Erlang (what kind of option I need to set) to get correct result of character size? I wold like get {match,[{0,1}]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **ucp** instead of **unicode** option.

```
>re:run("étude", "é",[ucp]).    
{match,[{0,1}]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yuri! I do not use `ucp` along (with unicode only).